# Windows 7 ATI Radeon Quad DVI no longer working with HDMI devices

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video, hdmi, amd-radeon

Graphics card is a GeCube Radeon HD3870X2 X-Turbo Quad DVI ports with (HDCP Support)
Memory: 1GB GDDR3
Bus:    PCI Express 2.0 x16
Connectors: DVI
DVI-I & TV Out

Upgraded to Windows 7 from VISTA and started to have problems with 2 of the 4 displays not getting any signal. I've been using 2 DVI 24" LCD monitors and 2 HDMI 32" monitors all worked fine until I upgraded OS, then again when I upgraded MB and RAM.

After I upgraded to Windows 7 the 2 HDMI stopped getting signal, uninstalling and re-installing ATI video drivers finally got signal to all 4 devices, took multiple installs to resolve.

The same thing when I upgraded MB and RAM after screwing with it for weeks finally got all 4 to work. Rebooted and now only the 2 DVI monitors are recognized, no signal to HDMI monitors.

I don't know what's different. Temperature is normal on graphics card, CPU and RAM. GECUBE and ATI/AMD have provided little or no support.

Video
GeCube Radeon HD3870X2 X-Turbo Quad DVI ports,

CPU
Intel Q9650 BX80569Q9650 3.00GHz 1333MHz FSB, 12MB Cache,

Ram
16GB RAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666),

Mother Board
Gigabyte GA-EP45T-DS3R,

Power Supply
Zephyr MX 750...

I would appreciate help from those more in-tune with the workings of GECUBE, ATI, Windows 7, video cards in general, crossfire, and HDMI...